# How to implement memory management system calls without having MMU

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, system-calls, virtual-memory, mmu

Let´s consider a task to design memory management for the OS kernel running on a system without MMU (like rather small embedded one). The target is to match the set of system calls to be UNIX (POSIX) compatible. There comes the idea to support either `brk()` / `sbrk()` to manage the data segment (heap) break or to manage the heap completely using `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag setup.

But both approaches work with virtual memory, am I right?

So in either case the system must support virtual memory but how to do so without having MMU on board? Maybe just the MPU?

To calculate the address translation somewhere within the kernel and to return virtual address from the brk()/sbrk()/mmap()? I can imagine that but then where to calculate the mapping from virtual to physical address usually done by MMU?

It seems the POSIX counts with MMU-equipped HW only, or? What would be the way of managing that on such a small embedded device - I expect the address recalculation done within SW causes big performance drop...

I just need to clarify the right approach to do so...

Comment: Why do you need virtual memory to manage heap? What prevents you to implement memory managment system calls not having mmu?

Comment: @AlexHoppus I have a kernel which si capable to allocate memory in pages to reduce syscalls for every single allocation. I would like to keep the option to add some more pages on process demand. You think I can manage that withou virtual memory? To have the heap splitted in many isolated memory blocks? My original idea was to map them in a contiguous memory section...

Comment: If you have loaded multiple processes into memory then you have quantified address space somehow. You have several processes with code,data,bss,stack loaded into address space (protected with MPU). Why (alongside with other segments) this processes can't have private heap? What exactly do you mean by "map them in a contiguous memory section"?

Comment: @AlexHoppus That is exactly the point - to have private heap for each process. But the heap consists of several pages, each having own physical address. So would it be the solution to “connect” them into one heap by for instance a linked list having the pages as list elements and to use this list as entity to manage by malloc()?

Comment: "So would it be the solution to “connect” them into one heap". What problem are you trying to solve by this "solution"? Why malloc can't use isolated heap for each process?

Comment: @AlexHoppus malloc() is about to use isolated heap for each process, but each process heap consists of several memory pages each of it having unique address. For instance process1 will have page 1,3,7 is it’s heap while other process2 is going to have pages 2,4,5,6 assigned / mapped. Once there is a virtual memory approach used, all the heap pages (1,3,7) can be merged into one contiguous address space but that requires MMU. So I am trying to find other solution to overcome this limit, you know?

Comment: You may preallocate physically continuous chunk of memory or keep track on this pages using linked list (inside allocator) as you said before.